# Reading web.config appsetting in another xml file

Tags: xml, configuration, web-config

I added

```
<add key="MySetting" value="3" />
```

in my web.config File. I need to use same setting in another config file (xml) for some other purpose(Nhibernate Mapping configuration related). How can i re-use the same setting in my new xml file.

Note: I can include same setting in my new xml file. but whenever the value changes, i need to modify both places. i want to avoid this.

Any help.?

Answer (score 0):

Try including another file with configSource
See https://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/using-configsource-to-split-configuration-files